# Issue with communities edit

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

My org has two active communities and I am the sys admin for it. I am unable to edit the community settings like giving public access for a page, etc as in the screen shot attached, I have no edit option provided. How can I edit that? Am i missing any permissions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can click on "force.com" link under Description for some settings and for more you can click on arrow under Actions and select "administrator settings"

If you want to edit url / domain of community then it is not possible to do so.

[image]

Comment: The description is not a link but only the description of the community. Also as in the picture, i dont see any arrow in Actions

Comment: You probably are missing something. Try following this.
On setup page. -> Search for communities -> select "All communitites"
you must be able to find arrow under Actions and "force.com" under custom pages. Then if you open "force.com", from there you should be able to give public access and/or to edit settings.